# My program will not stop after run() method in main thread finishes

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

I am using Java. The main thread sends data, while a worker thread listens to responses. I also have Timer in case timeout occurs. In main(), I am calling run(), which can finish, according to the output. Here is what it looks like:

```
class Send {
    Worker w;

    run() {
        // w was initialized in constructor
        w.start();
        ....
        w.join();
    }

    main(args) {
        Send s = new Send();
        s.run();
    }
    private class Worker extend Thread {
        public void run() {
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

In s.run(), every time I need to cancel the Timer or restart the Timer, I would do

```
timer.cancel();
timer.purge();
timer = new Timer();
timer.schdule(...);
```

The TimerTask is simply calling a static method in Send to handle the timeout.
So what did I do wrong to cause my program hanging after the main thread finishes?
Thank you.

---

EDIT: the out put of `kill -3 process-id`:

```
Full thread dump OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (19.0-b09 mixed mode):

"DestroyJavaVM" prio=10 tid=0x00007f9f20035000 nid=0x73f1 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Timer-10" prio=10 tid=0x0000000001a7d800 nid=0x740f in Object.wait() [0x00007f9f1e39c000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000075833fe78> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:505)
    - locked <0x000000075833fe78> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:484)

"Low Memory Detector" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f9f20004800 nid=0x7402 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"CompilerThread1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000001a70000 nid=0x7401 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f9f20001000 nid=0x7400 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000001a6e800 nid=0x73ff waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000001a49000 nid=0x73fe in Object.wait() [0x00007f9f1f3f2000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007580b1310> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:133)
    - locked <0x00000007580b1310> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:149)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:177)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000001a47000 nid=0x73fd in Object.wait() [0x00007f9f1f4f3000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007580b11e8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:133)
    - locked <0x00000007580b11e8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x0000000001a40000 nid=0x73fc runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00000000019d7000 nid=0x73f2 runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00000000019d9000 nid=0x73f3 runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00000000019da800 nid=0x73f4 runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00000000019dc800 nid=0x73f5 runnable 

"GC task thread#4 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00000000019de800 nid=0x73f6 runnable 

"GC task thread#5 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00000000019e0000 nid=0x73f7 runnable 

"GC task thread#6 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00000000019e2000 nid=0x73f8 runnable 

"GC task thread#7 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00000000019e4000 nid=0x73f9 runnable 

"GC task thread#8 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00000000019e5800 nid=0x73fa runnable 

"GC task thread#9 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00000000019e7800 nid=0x73fb runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00007f9f20007800 nid=0x7403 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 886

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 150528K, used 7745K [0x00000007580b0000, 0x00000007628a0000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 129088K, 6% used [0x00000007580b0000,0x00000007588405b8,0x000000075fec0000)
  from space 21440K, 0% used [0x00000007613b0000,0x00000007613b0000,0x00000007628a0000)
  to   space 21440K, 0% used [0x000000075fec0000,0x000000075fec0000,0x00000007613b0000)
 PSOldGen        total 343936K, used 0K [0x0000000608200000, 0x000000061d1e0000, 0x00000007580b0000)
  object space 343936K, 0% used [0x0000000608200000,0x0000000608200000,0x000000061d1e0000)
 PSPermGen       total 21248K, used 3130K [0x00000005fdc00000, 0x00000005ff0c0000, 0x0000000608200000)
  object space 21248K, 14% used [0x00000005fdc00000,0x00000005fdf0ea30,0x00000005ff0c0000)
```

Comment: is your worker's run() method logically ending?

Comment: You have to create a non-daemon thread and run it to have the application running.
If you have only daemon threads, the process exits.

Comment: Looks like you have a Timer thread still running - Timer-10 thread is in WAIT state. You are probably not invoking cancel() on one of your Timer objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Java program will exit after the last thread finishes.

To prevent that, mark the other threads as daemon threads.

Comment: I guess that this is what the OP doesn't want.

Comment: *To prevent that, mark the other threads as daemon threads.* And that has 3 votes (no comments). Should be: non-daemon.

Comment: @bsetsss: No. He seems to want to exit right after `main()` finishes

Comment: @SLask, oh yeah and it's funny actually. My bad for editing, imo hanging (in jargon) means the same as crashes.

Comment: @best: No.  Hanging and crashing are very different.  (Except that end-users like neither)

Comment: @SLaks, back in the day hanging use to happen (mostly) b/c an invalid cpu opcode, the same case now would be a crash. Crashing is supposed to terminated the process, and hanging to just cause no progress in the algorithm (either b/c of the OS "doesn't want" to schedule time quants or just b/c of an internal error like dead/live lock or an endless loop)

Comment: Set Timer to daemon did allow my program to finish, but I won't get timeout anymore. Should I schedule TimerTask differently, or have the TimerTask invoke my timeoutHandler() differently?

Comment: Hi, can I ask some questions? In java, if we assign a timer object to null value (timer = null;) without calling timer.stop() prior it, will the timer stop firing to the listener?

Answer (score 0):

Get a thread dump by running `kill -3 <process id>`. This will tell you which threads are hanging around & preventing the java process from exiting. Feel free to post (some of) the thread dump & folks can help you figure out what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are creating several Timer threads. Check that all of them have exited properly, that is probably the problem.

If you check the Timer JavaDoc - http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html - you will notice the following note:

> By default, the task execution thread does not run as a daemon thread

You can use a debugger (both Eclipse and NetBeans have excellent ones) to see which threads are still alive.